# I am trying to add GitHub authentication for Jenkins but got struck with an error while adding groups to Assign Roles in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, github-api

- I had created new OAuth app under GitHub and added the client ID and client screte to Jenkins.
  **Now I am trying to add the GitHub user groups to jenkins Assign Roles to give access to users but i am getting the fallowing error**

[image]

test*developers
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.acegisecurity.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthenticationToken
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm.loadGroupByGroupname(GithubSecurityRealm.java:730)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.matrixauth.AuthorizationContainerDescriptor.doCheckName_(AuthorizationContainerDescriptor.java:156)
    at hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doCheckName(GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.java:222)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:625)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$3.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:209)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

This seems linked to [Jenkins Security Advisory 2016-05-11](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2016-05-11/), and reported in [JENKINS-34775](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34775).

A plugin like [jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin (github pull requests builder plugin for Jenkins )](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin) fixed that in [ghprb-plugin PR 344](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/pull/344).

In the meantime, just for testing, try running Jenkins with `-Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true` to see if the error persists, just to confirm this is related to that security policy.